# Why did my default crontab editor change?

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

I have an Amazon Linux instance I have been using for years as a web server.  It's been awhile since I've logged in.  Today I logged in and noticed the default `crontab` editor has been changed from `nano` to `vi`.

I have looked, and for the life of me I can't figure out how to change it back to `nano`, which begs the question - how did it get changed universally in the first place?  What might have caused this?

My two questions are:

- How could this have happened?
- How can I change it back (permanently)?

I don't see anything in the logs or command history to help, but I'll note that I installed the new/latest `acme.sh` updater for Let's Encrypt a couple months ago, and it did install a cronjob for the root user (of which I was aware).

I can change the default editor back by either setting the `.selected_editor` file/value, or by `export EDITOR=/bin/nano`, but this seems to only address the issue for the current user (so, if I `crontab -e -u <otheruse>`, it edits as `vi` again), but I want the DEFAULT editor changed for `crontab`, so I always get the same editor, regardless of what user I'm working as.

Comment: Could be an OS patch update removed that default. Can you run `select-editor` from the command line and set the editor that way? Or check `~/.bash_profile` in your home directory and see if the value is set there.

Comment: I am suspicious of a patch update, but haven't seen anything in the logs that I would think would touch `cron`.  `select-editor` is not available on Amazon Linux.  `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, and `/etc/bashrc` do not seem to set the value anywhere.

Comment: Odd. Look at [these CentOS instructions](https://wiki.centos.org/EdHeron/EditorDefaultNano). I believe Amazon Linux is a cousin of CentOS in some way so perhaps that can help.

Comment: Thank you - changing the default editor in `/etc/profile.d/` helped, but running `sudo crontab -e -u <otheruser>` still runs the command in `vi`, so it's only the default within my profile (unless I export my editor with the `crontab -E` switch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual order for editors on Unix systems is as follows:

1. The value of the environment variable `VISUAL`, if the user has a TTY and the terminal is not dumb (i.e., `TERM` is set to something other than `dumb`).
2. The value of the environment variable `EDITOR`.
3. The default editor, `vi`.

Some systems, such as Debian, change this order slightly, usually by invoking a tool such as `sensible-editor` (from `sensible-utils`) to consider additional options between steps 2 and 3.  However, it doesn't appear that the current version of Amazon Linux uses this approach from my testing with a container.

If you're using a terminal editor like Nano, you probably just want to set `VISUAL` to `nano`.

However, as you've noticed, this doesn't work in some cases with `sudo` because it clears the environment by default, possibly excepting some variables such as `TERM`.  This is for security reasons, but not all systems have enabled this option by default, and it's possible that an upgrade caused this option to be set when it wasn't before.  You can use `sudo -E` to not clear the environment, either manually or through an alias, or you can run `sudo visudo` and remove a line like this one:

```
Defaults    env_reset
```

Note that, as mentioned, that has security considerations which you should read about in the manual page.

Comment: Super-helpful response.  In this specific instance, I used `sudo visudo` to add  `Defaults 
 env_keep +="VISUAL"`, after modifying the `/etc/profile.d/nano.sh` file to globally set the `VISUAL` environment variable, per @Giacomo1968 [CentOS](https://wiki.centos.org/EdHeron/EditorDefaultNano) above.